# Two different definitions for a model in first order logic?

Tags: logic, definition, first-order-logic, model-theory

So, if $T$ is a theory in a first order language $\mathcal L$, I thought a *model* for $T$ is

> a set $M$ with interpretations for all the constant, function and relation symbols of $\mathcal L$, in which all statements in $T$ are true.

But recently, I had someone calling a model

> a function $\beta$ that
>
> - assigns a truth value to each $\mathcal L$-statement,
> - assigns "true" to all statements in $T$, and
> - is compatible w.r.t. the usual inference rules, e.g. $\beta(\phi\land\psi)$ gives "true" if and only if $\beta(\phi)$ and $\beta(\psi)$ both give "true".

**Question:**

- Is the latter also called a *model* of $T$?
- Are these definitions equivalent, and if so, are they equivalent in an obvious way?

---

**Some thoughts**

So clearly, each "set-model" $M$ given such a "function-model" $\beta$ by defining

$$(*)\quad \beta(\phi)=\text{"true"}\;\Longleftrightarrow \; M\Vdash \phi$$

Also, if $T$ is inconsistent by proving $\phi\land \neg\phi$, then we cannot choose a value for $\beta(\phi)$, and so no such "function-model" exists.

The other direction seems non-obvious.
I can imagine that the equivalence follows from *Gödel's completeness theorem*, but I am uncertain.
Is it true that for every choice of such a "function-model" $\beta$ there is a "set-model" $M$ so that $(*)$ holds?

Comment: Where did you see the other definition discussed?

Comment: @NoahSchweber This was my interpretation of the vague definition of "model" given in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3766959/415941). Since I am only a layman when it comes to mathematical logic I got curious whether I missed something.

Comment: The OP's description of models is incorrect (and [Asaf Karagila's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3767513/28111) points this out - including the propositional/first-order issue I mention below).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that second definition is totally unsatisfactory (for first-order logic anyways - it's the correct definition for *propositional* logic).

First, let me rephrase it slightly. By thinking about $\beta^{-1}(\{\top\})$ instead of $\beta$ itself, we see that it's just a definition of a **maximal consistent theory containing $T$**.  This is a bit easier to think about in my opinion, so I'll do so. Maximal consistent sets (even with additional bells and whistles - see below) are definitely *not* the same things as a models, for two big reasons:

- Until we prove the completeness theorem, we don't know that a maximal consistent $S$ has a model.
- More fundamentally, maximal consistent theories do not have *unique* models up to isomorphism (unless they're the theories of finite structures), per the compactness theorem. Put another way, **isomorphism is finer than elementary equivalence** (and indeed inasmuch as model theory studies complete theories - which is most of the time, really - it's leaning on the *richness* which can occur within a single elementary equivalence class).

---

Now to be fair, if you really really want to avoid talking about sets you could look at expansions of the language instead and get something kinda-reasonable. Specifically, a "syntax-only model" of a theory $T$ in a language $\mathcal{L}$ could be defined as a pair $(S, \hat{\mathcal{L}})$ where:

- $\hat{\mathcal{L}}\supseteq \mathcal{L}$,
- $S$ is a maximal consistent $\hat{\mathcal{L}}$-theory containing $T$, and
- $S$ has the **witness property**: whenever $\exists x_1,...,x_n\varphi(x_1,...,x_n)$ is a sentence in $S$, there are closed $\hat{\mathcal{L}}$-terms $t_1,...,t_n$ such that $S\vdash\varphi(t_1,...,t_n)$. *(I've said a bit about the importance of the witness property [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3373679/28111) which may be relevant.)*

Such a syntax-only model has a naturally associated structure in the usual sense which (has a reduct which) is indeed a model of $T$. Moreover, every consistent theory has a syntax-only model; this is really what Henkin's argument shows. So we can get *something* via a syntax-only approach (but we have to add the witness property, which isn't stated in your second definition - or at best is unclearly implicit in its final buletpoint).

However, not all models of $T$ will occur this way. In particular, any model of $T$ with cardinality $>\vert T\vert+\aleph_0$ will not be so represented. So again, lots of model-theoretic topics vanish if we make this shift (or at least require tedious circumlocutions).